# HelloCordova uninstalled mistakenly on my android phone but need to reinstall it, cordova run in the CLI does not do it

Tags: android, cordova

I mistakenly uninstalled HelloCordova on my android phone. It was installed as a result of having deployed a Cordova  app to my phone using the Cordova CLI. I want to deploy another Cordova app to my phone but I think it is not working because I removed HelloCordova. When I use cordova run in the CLI to deploy another app to my phone it does not work...

The HelloCordova logo is not visible on my homescreen list of apps but it is still listed in my app settings labelled as uninstalled.
I presume that to deploy another app to my phone to test it I would need HelloCordova installed. When I try to do deploy a new Cordova app the the command line shows no signs that this hasn't worked but the new app is not visible anywhere on my phone presumably because I mistakenly uninstalled the HelloCordova app that popped up the last time I deployed an app to my phone.

Does Cordova install HelloCordova to your phone the first time you deploy an app to the phone? 
If you want to deploy more than one app to your phone do they all appear within the HelloCordova app?

Very new to this as you can tell.
Thanks, Hannah

Comment: One does not need one app to install another; there's a `pm` package manager.

Answer (score 0):

As Martin says there's no need to have HelloCordova installed. Are you running the other app from the command line? If so run
`cordova build android` this should create an .apk file - and will tell you the full path to it. Then connect your phone via USB and run `adb install {full path}`. This should install the app or give an error message that will allow you to track down what's happening

Comment: Thanks, that is so helpful. I have a device and an emulator so when I try what you suggest it tells me so. I'm trying to run it on the device, how do I specify the device? Is there a way to query the name of the devices/emulators associated with my Cordova installation? Thank you very much.

Comment: plug the device into the PC with usb and run 'adb devices' to see if you see it registered. If you don't see it check if the phone has had developer mode enabled in settings

Comment: I've found a device and emulator so I tried adb -s {long number of for found device} install {full path ending .apk} and it said no such file or directory...

Comment: what happens if you close your emulator and run add without the -s?

Comment: I got it to not fail when installing using cordova run android --target={device number} however there is a bigger problem, I cannot find the helloWorld app on my phone, it was uninstalled but it still exists in the list of apps as uninstalled. At what point did the helloWorld app get installed on the phone would it have been the first time I ran a cordova project to the phone via the command line? How could I get the app back?

Comment: using cordova run android --target forced it to look for the device which it found and then amazingly it loaded the app (recreating the uninstalled helloCordova application along the way). Thank you so much MStoner your advice was so helpful, I have learnt a lot.